# Transfer directories through FTP but just images and videos

Tags: linux, ftp, command

can you help me with an command to send through ftp images to remote directory... For example I have this filesystem:

```
/directory
    image.png
    index.php
    index.html
    video.mpeg
/directory2
    image.jpg
    index.html
/directory3
    /directory
        index.html
        image.jpg
```

And when I run command I would like to transfer just files with specific extensions (for now jpg, png and mpeg), so my desire result on remote folder is:

```
/directory
    image.png
    video.mpeg
/directory2
    image.jpg
/directory3
    /directory
        image.jpg
```

Is there any command which can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming these are just generic *nix systems then [`rsync`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) is better suited to this kind of task than [`ftp`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ftp), e.g.

```
rsync -av path/ remote-system:path/ --include \*/ --include \*.jpg --include \*.png --include \*.mpeg --exclude \*
```